# Is their a way i can put a sum and average of array functions together to create one function?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I need the sum and average functions to be combined to make my code shorter. My teacher said I don't need to add a function for the average I can just print average by dividing `sum/n`?

```
import random

def main():

    random_numbers = [random.randrange(1,100) for _ in range (10)]
    print(random_numbers)

    numbers = random_numbers

    total = get_total(numbers)
    print("Sum:", total)

    average = get_average(numbers)
    print("Average:", average)


def get_total(value_list):
    total = 0
    for num in value_list:
        total += num
    return total

def get_average(value_list):
    return get_total(value_list)/len(value_list)


main()
```

This is an example of what the output should look like (I have the correct output btw):

```
    [58, 25, 15, 66, 26, 58, 50, 12, 75, 48]
    Sum: 433
    Average: 43.3
```

Comment: Good answers, but if you want to return the values so you can use them later, you should return a tuple like (sum, average)

Comment: What exactly would a code like that look like?

Comment: In your get_total() function, just add a variable `average = total/len(value_list)` and return total, average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do the multiple return statements. You can print right from a function.

```
import random

def main():

    random_numbers = [random.randrange(1,100)
                for _ in range (10)]
    print(random_numbers)

    numbers = random_numbers

    getInformation(numbers)


def getInformation(value_list):
    total = 0
    for num in value_list:
        total += num
    print("Sum: " + total)
    print("Average: " +total/len(value_list))


main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this code worked with a little tweaking. I just had to add a coma after the end of the quotations for "Sum:" and "Average:". All in all it worked so thank you this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please mark my answer with the checkmark below the up and down arrows if this answer satisfied you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the shortest code:

```
import random

def main():

    random_numbers = [random.randrange(1,100)
                for _ in range (10)]
    print(random_numbers)

    numbers = random_numbers

    total = sum(numbers)
    print("Sum:", total)
    print("Average:", total/len(numbers))

main()
```

Comment: Thanks this is way shorter than my code i appreciate your time. I will defiantly be using this method in the future :)